# Please avoid creation of tags with full-width alphanumeric characters

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tags, localization, international-sites

At [Stack Overflow for Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) (SOja), we can use full-width alphanumeric characters for tags. In Japanese, these characters are used almost the same as their half-width version.

Example:

```
half-width: a
full-width: ａ

half-width: 1
full-width: １
```

At SOja, we prefer to use half-width characters for tags, and the system also tends to support to use half-width tags. In fact, at SOja, a tag written by full-width alphanumeric characters are *usually* identified with its half-width version. For example, if we move a mouse cursor on a tag [ｃ], it shows a tag description of a tag [c].

[image: A screenshot of a tag description of the full-width c]

They, however, are *not* tag-synonyms. We can still tag a question by a full-width one. Searching by a tag is also treating them as different tags.

Example:

- [c] https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c
- [ｃ] https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%83

Also, it seems that low-rep users can use a full-width tag if its half-width version exists. For this reason, it often happens that full-width tags are used wrongly.

Currently, SOja users correct these tags by hand, which is time-consuming. Related issues were post to SOja Meta in the past ([1](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/19110), [2](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2405/19110)), but a SOja manager at that time [said](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2405/%E5%85%A8%E8%A7%92%E8%8B%B1%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E3%82%92%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AB%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84#comment1837_2405) "This is difficult to fix. The root cause of this problem is the difference of character handling between SQL and C#".

But it is troublesome to check all tags and detect full-width characters manually. Is it possible to avoid creation of tags with full-width alphanumeric characters? For example, can we restrict these characters (say, U+FF01...U+FF5E) for tags? Or, can we treat them as half-width characters like tag synonyms?

Comment: How extensive is this?  Can these full width characters only be used on SOja, on international sites, or can they be used for tags any Stack Exchange site?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Nice comment. I also want to know that. I cannot fully confirm that due to my low reputation at other sites. At least I confirmed that I cannot tag a question with full-witdh [ｃ] at [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/) on the question creation page `/questions/ask`, but can tag at [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I made a quick edit to test, and while it allowed me to create a tag named `testingg`, it didn't allow that for  `ｔｅｓｕｔｏ`. So maybe this is only enabled on SOja (+ possibly other international sites).

Comment: I admit to not being an expert in typesetting but I wouldn't even now how to make full vs half width characters... and I don't even know what the characters I type with are... so that kinda argues that maybe it's not even a thing people think about in English?

Comment: @Catija English = halfwidth, I believe. To type in fullwidth usually you'd use an IME to convert keyboard input into a different character set. [example](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/how-to-type-in-japanese/)

Comment: Also at Chinese.SE, e.g. [ｃ](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%EF%BD%83).

Comment: O r  j u s t  t y p e  a  s p a c e  i n b e t w e e n  e a c h  c h a r a c t e r  t o  s e e  h o w  r e d i c u l o u s  t h i s  l o o k s.

Comment: And then the comment editor removed all my doubled up spaces...

Comment: @Luuklag No, full-width alphanumeric characters are commonly used in order to make typographic harmony with Japanese Hiragana/Katakana/Kanji, which are full-width by default. So they are not margined half-width characters, but characters designed for the special purpose. Here, we SOja users want to use half-width characters for a tag name because it often contains English words.

Comment: We've reviewed this request and have moved it to our backlog. I've updated the status to status-deferred. (I meant to leave this comment when I edited tags earlier, but forgot.)